# How to prove $(\lozenge \square p \land \lozenge \square q) \to \square \lozenge (p \land q)$ in $B$?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I am trying to prove in a Hilbert system $(\lozenge \square p \land \lozenge \square q) \to \square \lozenge (p \land q)$ in $B$. I am stuck with $(\square p \land \square q) \to \square \lozenge (p \land q)$ and I don't know how to get $\lozenge \square$ for each conjunct in the antecedent. Any help is appreciated.

I've tried substitutions of the $B$ axiom using $\lozenge \square p \land \lozenge \square q / p$ to no avail. I have derived $\lnot(\lozenge \square p \land \lozenge \square q) \to \square \lozenge \lnot (p \land q)$ so far starting from $\square(p \land q) \equiv \square p \land \square q$. I am unsure where to go from here.

Comment: Hint: The axiom p -> necessary(possible(p)) is logically equivalent to possible(necessary(q)) -> q for q := not(p).

Comment: @Rafi I have that piece of information and I still got stuck.

Comment: Welcome to mse! What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thanks for your willingness to help. I've made edits to my post about what I've tried.

Comment: @RW_123 Yes, that's the part I can't derive. I can clearly see how once you've derived that, you can prove the conditional.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof I found:

$\qquad\begin{array}{rl}
1. &(♢◻p∧♢◻q)→♢◻p\\
2. &♢◻p→p \\
3. &(♢◻p∧♢◻q) →p\\
4. &(♢◻p∧♢◻q) →q\\
5. & (♢◻p∧♢◻q) →(p∧q)\\
6. &♢(♢◻p∧♢◻q) →♢(p∧q)\\
7. &(♢◻p∧♢◻q) →◻♢(p∧q)\end{array}$

(7 follows from 6 from the theorem derivable in B: $⊢♢p→q \implies ⊢p→◻q$)